# Having trouble getting elements in internet explorer -- works with Chrome, Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have a `<textarea>` defined like this:

```
<textarea class="form-control notetext" id="{{this._id}}-notetext" name="notetext">{{this.text}}</textarea>
```

I use ajax to send data and load a partial webpage.

Then I try to find the `<textarea>` and list the results to the console.

The problem is that `elements[0]` is returning `undefined` in Internet Explorer 11 (haven't tried any other versions), but works fine in Chrome and Firefox. I have tried 3 variations which all give the same result. Is there a solution?

```
$.get('/page/' + Id + '/partial/', function(res) {
    $('#sectional').html(res);

    //variation 1
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('notetext');

    //variation 2
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.notetext');

    //variation 3
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
});
```

Also, please note that `id` is dynamically created, so I can't `.getElementById` (which would only return 1 result instead of an array). I saw a post somewhere that had a method to use regex on `.getElementById`, but it returned null as well.

Comment: Try to wrap getting the element in a `setTimeout()` callback with some small timeout like 100.

Comment: So `elements` is `[null]`?

Comment: @MaratTanalin: Good idea. I tried it, but even after waiting 1000ms it is still undefined.

Comment: @borisdiakur: actually, it is undefined.

Comment: You might want to check that your HTML is well-formed through the w3c validator

Answer (score 1):

...and it turned out that it was working in IE11 after all. I was originally using `getElementsbyName` which doesn't work properly in IE11 (it gets ID instead). So I changed it to the variations listed above, which all gave the same incorrect result. But after I quit and restarted the browser, the code worked fine. I'm not sure if I can change a setting somewhere in IE so this doesn't happen again?